# Trying to open Power Bi from an external site

Tags: apache-spark, hive, odbc, powerbi

I am trying to open up Power Bi from a website and also carry over the Hive data tables that will be used.  Currently i am looking into using Spark but keep hitting dead ends.  I have tried doing Power Bi online but i am limited to using 1 Gb of memory.    The desktop app would be ideal if possible.  I need some hints or suggestions on where to go from here.

Comment: Can you explain from which website you are opening Power BI?

Comment: The website does not really matter. I mostly need to know how to open a desktop app from a website.

Comment: May I know if you are trying to embed power bi into your application?
If this is the case, you should read about Power BI embedded.
Else there are various stuff in Power BI. Please Read about it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/power-bi-embedded/
Link for Power BI embedded.